# Is there a way to duplicate entire AWS environment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know I can create image from my existing instance and relaunch them later, what I want to know is if there is a way to duplicate my whole environment, like duplicate every VM in UAT to create Beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [AWS CloudFormer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) to generate CFN templates of existing resources, which you can modify and re-deploy.

Make sure that you are very familiar with CloudFormation before doing this, though, as there are many ways you could harm your current environment if you're not careful.

You may even consider deploying the templates in a separate AWS account to minimize chances of something bad happening.